# seams are unwrapping tangled on uv editing screen

Tags: mesh, uv, shrinkwrap

I am currently in the process of unwrapping seams.

Here is my blender file: https://pasteall.org/blend/162331c146b54caaa91a7480ea1f33ff

Blender version 3.1.0. Reference tutorial I am following, around 14:30: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEBwBrRzyhw&t=878s

When unwrapping my seams, they unwrap tangled, as pictured:
[image]

However, when i unwrap them individually, they are laid out perfectly.

I have attempted smart wrapping but it does not help. If I could put the individual wraps on one page, that would be good too.

Any suggestions on how I could go about this, or if anyone has experienced this before?

Much appreciated

Comment: Hi :). Unwrap should be pretty simple on this one. Consider sharing your file so others can take a look: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: just uploaded! Updated my question! @JachymMichal

Comment: Hi :). It unwraps just fine on my machine. Could be a bug I guess...

Comment: Could you link the file with the unwrapping done? I am completely stumped. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: oh sure, just a minute

Comment: Here it is all unwrapped :) https://pasteall.org/blend/b0740c09febe4ccea65d9be9114f6eb4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pack all the islands into UV space by using *UV > Pack Islands*.
It should give similar result as unwrapping all at once.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help!!! I still have not been able to successfully unwrap, and it looks like it may be a bug with my blender as others have been able to do it as well. Much appreciated! Will probs report the bug!

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project :)